# VisualG - Prog para limites

Tags: portugol, visualg

Estou fazendo o programa do seguinte exercício:

> Crie um algoritmo que leia os limites inferior e superior de um
>   intervalo e imprimir todos os números ímpares no intervalo aberto e
>   seu somatório (UTILIZE O PARA). Suponha que os dados digitados são
>   para um intervalo decrescente.

Minha dúvida é, como faço para ele não exibir os números digitados? Porque devo imprimir o intervalo aberto, e neste, ele não deve exibir os números digitados.

```
algoritmo "APS08"
var
   inf, sup, soma:inteiro
   i:inteiro
inicio

      escreva("Digite o limite inferior: ")
      leia(inf)
      escreva("Digite o limite superior: ")
      leia(sup)

      para i de inf ate sup faca passo -1
           se (i%2 = 1) entao
              escreva(i)

              soma <- soma + i
           fimse
      fimpara

      escreval("")
      escreval("Soma: ",soma)

fimalgoritmo
```

Alguém pode me explicar como faço?

**[RESOLUÇÃO]**

```
algoritmo "APS08"
var
   inf, sup, soma:inteiro
   i:inteiro
inicio

      escreva("Digite o limite inferior: ")
      leia(inf)
      escreva("Digite o limite superior: ")
      leia(sup)

      para i de sup-1 ate inf-1 passo -1 faca
           se (i%2 = 1) entao
              escreva(i)

              soma <- soma + i
           fimse
      fimpara

      escreval("")
      escreval("Soma: ",soma)

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: como assim *"não exibir os números digitados"*? quer esconder o comando `leia`?  Como vai saber o que está sendo digitado? Se quiser tirar da tela depois, só usar o comando `limpatela`

Comment: Não amigo. Suponha que o limite inferior é 5 e o superior é 10. Ele vai exibir todos os ímpares de 5 até 10 (5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25). O 5 e o 25 não devem aparecer. Entende? E ainda deveria estar mostrando em ordem decrescente.

Comment: Entendi, você pode tratar isso no `para`, não comece a partir de `inf` mas `inf+1` e a mesma ideia no `ate`, e se quiser inverter a ordem inveta também onde começa e onde termina o `para`

Comment: Fiz a alteração, ficou `para i de inf+1 ate sup-1 passo -1` e resolveu o problema. Quanto a ordem decrescente, nada. Quando eu inverti a ordem, ele parou de exibir.

Comment: Se você inverter a ordem, precisa também inverter o passo: `para i de  sup-1  ate inf+1 passo 1`

Comment: Já achei o problema. Aquele bom e velho "erro entre a cadeira e o monitor". Agradeço sua ajuda, e vou editar o post com a resolução.

Comment: você pode postar a solução como resposta que é o mais correto

Comment: Ok. Nos próximos posts, farei isso. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

O limite inferir está incorreto. Veja um teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é um *intervalo aberto*, só deveriam ser considerados os valores entre 2 e 9 (inclusos). O 1 não deveria entrar.

Para corrigir, apenas altere de "-" para "+" para o inferior. Exemplo:

De:

> `para i de sup-1 ate inf-1 passo -1 faca`

Para:

```
para i de sup-1 ate inf+1 passo -1 faca
```

Segue outra forma:

```
algoritmo "APS08"
var
   inferior, superior, somatorio: inteiro
   ultimo, primeiro:  inteiro
   i:inteiro
inicio
   escreva("Digite o limite inferior: ")
   leia(inferior)
   escreva("Digite o limite superior: ")
   leia(superior)

   //encontrar o último ímpar da sequência
   se (superior % 2 = 0) entao //se par
      ultimo <- superior - 1
   senao
      ultimo <- superior - 2
   fimSe

   //encontrar o primeiro ímpar da sequência
   se (inferior % 2 = 0) entao //se par
      primeiro <- inferior + 1
   senao
      primeiro <- inferior + 2
   fimSe

   escreval()
   escreva ("Intervalo aberto:")
   para i de ultimo ate primeiro passo -2 faca //os ímpares alternam de 2 em 2
      escreva (i)
      somatorio <- somatorio + i
   fimpara

   escreval("")
   escreval("Somatório: ", somatorio:1)
fimAlgoritmo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]